# Routing Issue, Index Action Must Be Explicitly Called?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm using the LowerCasedDashedRoutes package in an MVC Project and wrote this line...

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.Add(new LowercaseDashedRoute("{action}",
    new RouteValueDictionary(
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }),
    new DashedRouteHandler()
  )
);
```

This works great when I want to remove the **Home** controller name from the URL and simply call the action I want within that controller. But when I want to go to a different controller say **Codes** with a URL like **http://www.mydomain.com/codes** I would like the default **Index** action of the **Codes** controller to display. Instead, I get a 404 unless I type out **http://www.mydomain.com/codes/index** What do I need to write to get this to work?

Comment: for that you need to define a new route

Comment: Sounds great, can you provide me with some code for this new route?

Comment: Are you able to help with the code?

Answer (score 0):

add something like this route

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Codes",
  "codes/{id}",
  new { Controller = "codes", action = "Index", id= UrlParameter.Optional },
  new[] { "YourProjectName.Controller" } // namespace of the code controller
);
```